# non-static method readData(GoogleApiClient,DataReadRequest) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android

How do I fix the above error.

I'm creating `datareadrequest` in the `doInBackground` of `GetCaloriesAsyncTask` using the below line. But its not working.

```
DataReadResult dataReadResult =   HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [HistoryApi documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryApi), you must use `Fitness.HistoryApi.readData`:

```
DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest)
    .await(1, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

`Fitness.HistoryApi` is actually a static instance of the `HistoryApi` object on the `Fitness` class, allowing you to call `readData` on that actual object. What you are trying to do is access a static method on the `HistoryApi` class which does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Call `HistoryApi.readData` as below in `doInBackground` of your `Asynctask`:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DataReadResult dataReadResult =   HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                }
            });
```

Hope this helps.